# How to compare first letter of a mobile number i.e 0 or not on keyup() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, function

I want to compare first letter of mobile number i.e zero or not.
but the problem is it execute every time when i press a key means it shows errors multiple time according to number of key i pressed.

```
$("input[name='phone_mobile']").keyup(function(){
        var newMobile = $("input[name='phone_mobile']").val();
        if(newMobile.charAt(0) == '0'){
        $('.phone_mobile').append('<span style="color:#a94442">Mobile number can't start from zero</span>');
        }
    })
```

Comment: The comparison logic is correct. The problem is simply due to the mismatched quotes in the HTML string you append. You can see the issue in the syntax highlighting of the snippet.

Comment: As mentioned by @RoryMcCrossan, you may just need to add "\" for escape characters `$('.phone_mobile').append('<span style="color:#a94442">Mobile number can\'t start from zero</span>');`

Comment: Did you read what the error told you?  They're quite informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function GETS EXECUTED EVERYTIME YOU PRESS A KEY ... YOU CANNOT PREVENT THAT

But You can control how many times your error msg appears in so many ways

We will use one variable isAlreadyInformed

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="phone_mobile" />
  <div class="phone_mobile"></div>
  <script>
    let isAlreadyInformed = false;
    //adding the keyup event
    $("#phone_mobile").keyup(function() {
      //this function GETS EXECUTED EVERYTIME YOU PRESS A KEY ... YOU CANNOT PREVENT THAT
      //But You can control how many times your error msg appears in so many ways
      //We will use one variable isAlreadyInformed                    
      var newMobile = $("#phone_mobile").val();
      if (newMobile.charAt(0) == '0') {
        if (!isAlreadyInformed) {
          $('.phone_mobile').append('<span style="color:#a94442">Mobile number can\'t start from zero</span>');
        }
        isAlreadyInformed = true;
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<head><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
    <input name="phone_mobile" />
    <span class="phone_mobile"></span>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[name='phone_mobile']").keyup(function () {
        var newMobile = $("input[name='phone_mobile']").val();
        if (newMobile.charAt(0) == '0') {
            $('.phone_mobile').html('<span style="color:#a94442">Mobile number can\'t start from zero</span > ');
       }else{
           $('.phone_mobile').html('');
       }
    });
</script>
```

You need to escape a comma and also there should not be append instead you need to replace html code so that previous messages wont pileup in html, so replace your code with code that i have given, i have added `<span>` tag with `class="phone_mobile"`:

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the append method of jquery which will append the output every time. You can use `text()` or `html()` method to solve this issue.

```js
$("input[name='phone_mobile']").keyup(function() {

  var newMobile = $("input[name='phone_mobile']").val();
  if (newMobile.charAt(0) == '0') {
    $('.phone_mobile').text("Mobile number can't start from zero.");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="phone_mobile" type="text"> 
<span class="phone_mobile"  style='color:#a94442'></span>
```